# SDNestedTable expand does not work on iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, custom-controls, nested-table

After clicking on a cell it doesn't expand.
The issue is reported on [github](https://github.com/serverdensity/ios-SDNestedTable/issues/21).
The issue occurs only for iOS 7. On previous versions everything works fine.

Comment: This is off-topic because it's not a question.

Comment: I faced a problem and did not find any solution. I have decided to post here an issue and my solution, because many people start their search from Stack Overflow

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue is that expanded index paths are stored in `NSDictionary`, where `NSIndexPath` is key.
In iOS 7 method `-(CGFloat)tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` receives `UIMutableIndexPath` object instead of `NSIndexPath` object. So value from dictionary can't be retrieved.
Here is this method in SDNestedTableViewController.m:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int amt = [[subItemsAmt objectForKey:indexPath] intValue];
    BOOL isExpanded = [[expandedIndexes objectForKey:indexPath] boolValue];
    if(isExpanded)
    {
        return [SDGroupCell getHeight] + [SDGroupCell getsubCellHeight]*amt + 1;
    }
    return [SDGroupCell getHeight];
}
```

The simplest solution is create some key that will have values from `indexPath`. And will be member of `NSIndexPath` class. So I've changed this method in following way:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPathKey = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section];
    int amt = [[subItemsAmt objectForKey:indexPathKey] intValue];
    BOOL isExpanded = [[expandedIndexes objectForKey:indexPathKey] boolValue];
    if(isExpanded)
    {
        return [SDGroupCell getHeight] + [SDGroupCell getsubCellHeight]*amt + 1;
    }
    return [SDGroupCell getHeight];
}
```